# determine if two vertices are connected jGraphX

Tags: java, vertex, jgraphx

Is there a method to determine if two vertices are connected in JgraphX? The method `isConnectable()` only returns true if the vertex is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it by checking the edges. In this example, being *cell1* the first cell you have and *cell2* the cell you want to check if its connected with *cell1*.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cell1.getEdgeCount(); i++) {
   mxCell source = ((mxCell) cell1.getEdgeAt(i)).getSource();
   mxCell target = ((mxCell) cell1.getEdgeAt(i)).getTarget();
   if (source == cell2 || target == cell2)
       return true;
   else
       return false;
}
```

You need to check both source and target 'cause you can't be sure if *cell1* will be the source or the target in that iteration. This way, you iterate every cell that is connected to *cell1* and checks if it is equal to a second cell.

Comment: Is the `==` operator appropriate here or should the `equals()` method be used instead?

Comment: @entpnerd You should use `==`. I'm not completely sure, but I guess the `.equals()` method can only be implemented in objects that extends the _class_ Object. From what I know, mxCell does not extends it (but you should check it). Anyway, basically you should use `.equals()` to compare Strings, and `==` to compare other objects. Take a look in this article, it will definitely explain better than I do
http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/